# Integrate flash games in android app?

Tags: android, flash, webview, integrate

Have 3 flash games that I would like to integrate in a menu / list in an android app. So when the user selects the game from the list, the game starts with help of android flash player.

Is it best to do this with WebView or is there something better? I do not know where to place the flash games to get them in my compiled application.

Is there a good tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adobe flash provides one good way: You can build an air for android app. Use that to create your menu and compile all three games into your AIR app.

Here are some tutorial links about it and also about publishing AIR for Android applications:

AIR to Android, PART1: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=123

AIR to Android, PART2: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=124

Publishing AIR for Android applications: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=131

I don't believe the android flash player can be launched from an intent yet, so using the Java Android will not solve it (for now)

And a third approach you mentioned, ought to work - using a webview.

Comment: please will you explain or suggest any tutorials for this answer